# Entity Framework Code First - Mapping a table to another with both single and multiple relations?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I am trying to set up a relationship where a Car can have multiple Testruns, as well as an optionally selected "active testrun".

```
public class Car
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public virtual TestRun ActiveTestRun { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TestRun> TestRuns { get; set; }
}


public class TestRun
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public double TopSpeed { get; set; }

    public virtual Car ActiveCar { get; set; }
    public virtual Car Car { get; set; }
}
```

I have been trying to use InverseProperties with or without ForeignKey-attributes but to no luck. What is the correct way to setup this kind of relation? TIA!

Ps. I think I tried mostly all of the combinations from this tutorial without getting it to work :(
http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/inverseproperty-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx

EDIT: The resulting DB-schema I would want is something like:

tbl_Cars:
ID, ActiveTestRunID[Nullable]

tbl_TestRuns:
ID, TopSpeed, CarID

Comment: Does this work with virtual members?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This achieved the result that I wanted:

```
public class Car
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int? ActiveTestRunID { get; set; }
    public virtual TestRun ActiveTestRun { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Car")]
    public virtual ICollection<TestRun> TestRuns { get; set; }
}


public class TestRun
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public double TopSpeed { get; set; }

    public int CarID { get; set; }
    public virtual Car Car { get; set; }
}
```